# slidetoggle for gridview in dynamically generated "expandable" rows

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Well, I have a situation where I need to provide a slidetoggle effect for my gridview's dynamically generated rows. I use a javascript + pagemethod to achieve the auto generation.

This is my ItemTemplate for the gridview

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="javascript:void">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgExpandCollapse" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/expand.png" onclick='ShowDetails(this);' ToolTip="Toggle"/></a>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUID" Style="display: none" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UID")  %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I use the following javascript to generate the rows dynamically by calling a web method.

```
function ShowDetails(ImgObj) {

    if (ImgObj.src.toLowerCase().indexOf("expand") != -1) {

        if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
            document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            var newTr = document.createElement("tr");
            newTd = document.createElement("td");
            var UID = document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "lblUID")).innerHTML;

            newTd.setAttribute("id", ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails"));
            newTd.setAttribute("colspan", "7");
            newTd.setAttribute("Style", "padding:0 0 0 0");
            newTd.innerHTML = "<div class='centerAlign'><img src='../Images/loading.gif'/></div>";
            PageMethods.GetLogResult(UID, OnSucceeded, OnFailed,newTd);

            newTr.appendChild(newTd);
            jQuery('#' + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRow")).after(newTr);
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/collapse.png";
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
            document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).style.display = "none";
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/expand.png";
    }

}


function OnSucceeded(result, newTd) {
    newTd.innerHTML = result;
}

function OnFailed(error) {
    alert(error.id);
}
```

Now the issue of using a Slidetoggle() is that these rows are autogenerated and they have different IDs. Now if somebody could help me out with this, I would be grateful. Thanks.

EDIT:
Apparently, I was trying to "slide" a table row, which aint supported for slidetoggle in Jquery. I changed the code and it worked :)

```
function ShowDetails(ImgObj) {

    if (ImgObj.src.toLowerCase().indexOf("expand") != -1) {

        if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
            $("#" + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).slideToggle();
        }
        else {
            var newTr = document.createElement("tr");
            newTd = document.createElement("td");
            newDiv = document.createElement("div");

            var UID = document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "lblUID")).innerHTML;

            newTd.setAttribute("colspan", "7");
            newTd.setAttribute("Style", "padding:0 0 0 0");

            newDiv.setAttribute("id", ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails"));
            newDiv.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='../Images/loading.gif'/>";
            PageMethods.GetLogResult(UID, OnSucceeded, OnFailed, newDiv);

            newTd.appendChild(newDiv);
            newTr.appendChild(newTd);

            jQuery('#' + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRow")).after(newTr);
            $("#" + newDiv.id).show();
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/collapse.png";
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
            $("#" + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).slideToggle();
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/expand.png";
    }
}

function OnSucceeded(result, newDiv) {
    newDiv.innerHTML = result;
}

function OnFailed(error) {
    alert(error.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected code which works.

```
function ShowDetails(ImgObj) {

        if (ImgObj.src.toLowerCase().indexOf("expand") != -1) {

            if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
                $("#" + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).slideToggle();
        }
        else {
            var newTr = document.createElement("tr");
            newTd = document.createElement("td");
            newDiv = document.createElement("div");

            var UID = document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "lblUID")).innerHTML;

            newTd.setAttribute("colspan", "7");
            newTd.setAttribute("Style", "padding:0 0 0 0");

            newDiv.setAttribute("id", ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails"));
            newDiv.setAttribute("style", "text-align:center");
            newDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='../Images/loading.gif'/>";
            PageMethods.GetLogResult(UID, OnSucceeded, OnFailed, newDiv);

            newTd.appendChild(newDiv);
            newTr.appendChild(newTd);

            jQuery('#' + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRow")).after(newTr);
            $("#" + newDiv.id).show();
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/collapse.png";
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById(ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")) != null) {
            $("#" + ImgObj.id.replace("imgExpandCollapse", "grdRowDetails")).slideToggle();
        }
        ImgObj.src = "../Images/expand.png";
    }
}

function OnSucceeded(result, newDiv) {
    newDiv.innerHTML = result;
}

function OnFailed(error) {
    alert(error.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the object's clientID as the paramerter for your function?

```
<asp:Image ID="imgExpandCollapse" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/expand.png" onclick='ShowDetails(<%=imgExpandCollapse.ClientID%>);' ToolTip="Toggle"/></a>
```